# ffmpeg only posting playlist but not segments for HLS

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am launching an ffmpeg process that is supposed to send the HLS "encoded" data to a webserver that will distribute it to the clients requesting it. I am using the following command line:

```
                "ffmpeg",
                "-hide_banner",
                "-f", "rawvideo",
                "-pixel_format", "rgb32",
                "-video_size", "800x600",
                "-framerate", "22",
                "-i", "-",
                "-f", "hls",
                "-c:v", "libx264",
                "-crf", "17",
                "-preset", "ultrafast",
                "-hls_time", "1",
                "-flags", "+cgop",
                "-g", "30",
                "-hls_segment_filename", "%d.ts",
                "-method", "POST",
                fmt::format("http://localhost:8082/video/{}/live.m3u8", _uuid)
```

or specifically `ffmpeg -hide_banner -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb32 -video_size 800x600 -framerate 22 -i - -f hls -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -preset ultrafast -hls_time 1 -flags +cgop -g 30 -hls_segment_filename %d.ts -method POST http://localhost:8082/video/ee811a74-7a48-4c4e-8c82-371c1cbbff05/live.m3u8`

The first few lines of the output look fine:

```
[hls @ 0x224aeb0] Opening '0.ts' for writing
Output #0, hls, to 'http://localhost:8082/video/ee811a74-7a48-4c4e-8c82-371c1cbbff05/live.m3u8':
```

The file name was picked up, the URL was also properly recognized. After the first file has been generated I also get a `POST` request to the URL mentioned above with the `live.m3u8` containing the following playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:1
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:1.363667,
0.ts
```

But I do not get the `0.ts` file posted to my webserver. This continues like that, the playlist keeps getting updated, but no segment files are posted to my server. They are all written to the disk and stay there forever.

Am I missing a flag?

Comment: Is your server configured to handle the POST requests and act on them?

Comment: Yes, In fact I dump every incoming http request no matter if there is a handler configured. I also did a few negative tests using invalid urls for the m3u8 to make sure they show up in the logs

Comment: Add the full path with protocol to the segment filename.

Comment: I was intially also adding `-hls_base_url http://localhost:8082/video/ee811a74-7a48-4c4e-8c82-371c1cbbff05/` and the playlist contained the full path, but ffmpeg was still not posting the segment files to my server.

Comment: @Gyan Now I understand what you meant, and indeed that fixed it: `"-hls_segment_filename", fmt::format("http://localhost:8082/video/{}/%d.ts", _uuid)` fixed it!

Comment: @Gyan Fyi I am leaving it up to you to answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hls_segment_filename` isn't just for the basename, but accepts fully qualified path including protocol. IF only a basename is supplied, then file protocol is assumed and working directory is used for output location.